# Need to 301 redirect a subpage with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

we want to relaunch our website and need to 301 redirect some pages. Can somebody help me with redirect them from a subpage with parameters to a subpage withour parameters?

from:

`www.example.com/pagee874.html?al=kontakt&amp;Publikation=Die%20besten%20Ideen%20f%C3%BCr%20eine%20starke%20Pers%C3%B6nlichkeit`

to

`www.example.com//publikationen/`

Comment: You mean front end user will hit url `www.example.com//publikationen/` and in backend it should point to that other url right? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: The customer printed some urls in catalog and they should be reachable after the relaunch. This page will be gone after the relaunch: 
www.example.com/pagee874.html?al=kontakt&amp;Publikation=Die%20besten%20Ideen%20f%C3%BCr%20eine%20starke%20Pers%C3%B6nlichkeit 

but it should still be rechable with a redirect to 

www.example.com/publikationen/

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^al=kontakt&amp;Publikation=Ich%20sehe%20was,%20was%20du%20nicht%20siehst$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pagee874.html/?$
RewriteRule .* /publikationen/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Could you please do let me know if you want to look for specific query string or you want to write rule for any query string?

Comment: No problem. I think it could help other users. 
I wanted to look for a specific query string, because we redirect from an old CMS wich use those query strings to identify target-page. 
I have 10 links wich directs to pagee874.html but all of the have different query strings.

Comment: Thanks for letting know. IMHO if those 10 links are having something common in logic we could still try to make a generic solution if you are ok with it :) cheers and happy learning, I will keep my answer as it is, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, in case you want to check if query string is not empty.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pagee874\.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /publikationen/? [R=301,NC,L]
```